# Delphi UTF8String convert to AnsiString explicit and implicit conversions have different results

Tags: delphi, delphi-11-alexandria, delphi-12-athens

I know UTF8String convert to AnsiString will cause data lost, but I found that explicit and implicit conversions are not the same.

The following code shows that explicit conversions from UTF8String to AnsiString still could show the emoji character and the length of the string is 6, while implicit conversions cause a data loss which I expected.

So why is that? Is there any documention or explaination of this behavior?

I tried under Delphi 11.3 and 12, both get the same results.

```pascal
var
  nUTFStr: UTF8String;
  nAStr1, nAStr2: AnsiString;
begin
  nUTFStr := 'Hi';

  nAStr1 := AnsiString(nUTFStr);
  nAStr2 := nUTFStr;

  ShowMessage(Format('%s, %d | %s, %d', [nAStr1, Length(nAStr1), nAStr2, Length(nAStr2)]));
end;
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Your description is backwards from your code. In any case, what you describe sounds like a compiler bug, because the two coversions *should* invoke the same logic (UTF-8 to UTF-16 to ANSI). Report the problem to Embarcadero.

Comment: Yes, my desc is wrong. I change the desc. Is that a bug?

Comment: It seems it is rather a feature other than a bug. Explicit conversions between AnsiStringBase will not has codepage conversion and will not change codepage. But implicit will.

Comment: The explicit assignment actually is a _variable typecast_, which calms down the compiler but keeps the underlying data as is. The implicit assignment does a conversion as expected.

Comment: I think it is just something Embarcadero decided. UnicodeString and AnsiString conversion always do the code page conversion, regardless the implicit or explicit conversions. Typecast assignment could have different implementations, it does not always follow the same rule.